# jquery mobile browser detection to css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm currently using the following code in DIVI to detect a mobile browser so that some features are turned off, by adding notonmobile to the CSS Class

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
.notonmobile {display: none;}
}
```

However I would like to be more specific due to the resolutions of devices and some functions do not work on mobile devices, I found a jQuery here http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Is there a simple way to merge the 2 so that if the query is true (mobile based browser) then the notonmobile value will work in the class??

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain a bit better what you want to do? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'd recommend Modernizr instead. It's one of the best, most robust feature detection libraries out there: https://modernizr.com/ . All features are added to the <HTML> tag.

Comment: Hi, DIVI (http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) allows me to build the page using blocks, when using parallax scrolling it does not work on mobile devices so I want to hide those blocks which is done using the code above and then setting the CSS class to notonmobile so the block is hidden. I would like to complete a browser detection and then use this variable to hide the block e.g. jquery sets a css varible of @mobile=true then the CSS code would be if @mobile=true then hide the block

Comment: You could do more with the width. Phones are usually 340px x 480px, whereas tablets can be 600+px. So if you want to just look at screen width versus OS type etc, this would be another way to do it.